# MySQL LEFT JOIN multiple tables logic problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables: `singers`, `songs`, `albums`.  They are all linked with `singer_id`

I need to get all of them even if there is no matching `singer_id`.  I managed to get all of them with this query:

```
   SELECT singers.singer_name, albums.album_name, songs.song_name 
     FROM singers
LEFT JOIN albums ON singers.singer_id = albums.singer_id 
LEFT JOIN songs ON albums.singer_id = songs.singer_id
    WHERE singer_id = ?
```

But the problem is I can;t display the results properly.

Let's say the singer have 3 albums and 11 songs.  This is how i display them...

Displaying the singer name:

```
echo $results[0]['singer_name']
```

Displaying the songs names:

```
foreach($results as $song) {
   // PROBLEM: instead of getting 11 songs i'm getting 33 results so each song show up 3 times.
   echo $song['song_name'] 
}
```

Displaying the albums:

```
foreach($results as $album) {
 // PROBLEM: i'm getting 33 albums instead of 3 each album shows up 3 times.
  echo $album['album_name'] 
}
```

EDIT:
the songs table have a reference to the albums table `album_id` but there are songs without an album yet so i need to get the results just by the `singer_id`

what i need to get is:
11 songs.
3 albums.
1 singer.

thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
this solution worked for me.
what i wanted is to get all songs for the specified singer id and albums
the results i wanted looks like this.

```
singer_name : song_name     : album_name
...............................................................
Jay Z       : 99 Problems   : NULL
Jay Z       : Gotta Have It : Watch the Throne
```

so i wanted to get all the singer songs even if they are not in any album yet.

this is the query that i used.

```
SELECT singers.singer_name, songs.song_name, albums.album_name
FROM singers
LEFT JOIN songs ON singers.singer_id = songs.singer_id
LEFT JOIN albums ON albums.album_id = songs.album_id
WHERE singers.singer_id = ?
```

thanks to @knittl i'm getting the results i need.

but there is another problem now.
i have 3 albums and 11 songs

the songs display correctly but when i make a `foreach` loop on the albums i get 33 albums again....

how can i display the albums correctly? i have just 3 albums.

Comment: Using that logic, you're getting a cross join.  A song should also be related to a specific album - what you're getting is a list of every song related to every album.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: The logic, yes - but not the LEFT JOIN'd query provided.  Either way, there's liable to be a lot of garbage data returned by the query.

Comment: #galacticcowboy i know that i can just reference the the album for the songs, but there are songs without an album attached to them yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want all songs. select from songs and perform a left join to get potential data from other tables (order by to get nicer representation):

```
SELECT a.artist_name, COALESCE(b.album_name, '(no album)'), s.song_name, 
FROM songs s
LEFT JOIN artists a
ON s.singer_id = a.singer_id
LEFT JOIN albums b
ON s.album_id = b.album_id AND s.singer_id = b.singer_id
ORDER BY a.artist_name, b.album_id
```

Comment: thanks that's a good solution but i'm having another problem now. look at my edit.

Comment: @parpardromi: please start a new question for such things. I've answered a similar question: [how to display changing values only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459201/array-how-to-display-the-changing-values-only/1459239#1459239)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you want are songs, a song must have an artist but may have/or not have an album :

SO :

```
SELECT     singers.singer_name, IF('' == albums.album_name, 'single', albums.album_name) AS album_name, songs.song_name 
FROM       songs   AS songs
RIGHT JOIN singers AS singers ON (singers.singer_id = songs.singer_id)
LEFT JOIN  albums  AS albums  ON (albums.singer_id = songs.singer_id)
WHERE      songs.singer_id = ?
```

Comment: what is the 'single' string ?

Comment: That query does not show songs without an artist. Also right joins should be avoided, since they reduce maintainability.